# CakePHP: $this->set(...) is empty in view?

Tags: cakephp

I can't seem to figure out how to use routing parameters and the set-function. Here is what I did:

Config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/professions/:linkname', array('controller' => 'professions', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Controller/ProfessionsController.php:

```
public function display($linkname = null) {
    $this->set('test', $linkname);
    //$this->set('profession', $this->findByLinkname($linkname));
}
```

View/Professions/display.ctp:

```
<?php echo $test; ?>
```

when I open /professions/test, the page is empty. Why? (As you can see, $test is only a test. I commented out what I really intended to do. But that is not working either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, RFTM... found it in the official book. Passing the parameters has to be specified like so:

```
Router::connect('/professions/:linkname', array('controller' => 'professions', 'action' => 'display'), array('pass' => array('linkname'));
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It explains in detail how to do what you're asking in the CakePHP Book here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Or, per Eike's answer (but in a less rude way), try this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/professions/:linkname',
    array(
        'controller' => 'professions',
        'action' => 'display'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array(
            'linkname'
        )
    )
);
```

Obviously you could put this all in one line if that's easier or if it's more to your liking.

Comment: Thank you, but it's ok to be rude, I was talking to myself there :>

Comment: LMAO.  You're right - you can be rude to yourself.  I need to L2Read usernames, eh? :)